# Griffon db4o plugin configuration

Tags: db4o, griffon

I'd like to use db4o inside Griffon app, but I've problem with configuration:
how to set up plugin to not delete dbFile during AppShutdown.
There is some info about configuration at plugin page:

```
def configure(EmbeddedConfiguration configuration) {dataSource.delete=???}
```

but hot exactly set datasource.delete = 'false'?
Thanks for your help.

panKonrad.

Answer (score 1):

Look closely at the different environments defined in Db4oConfig.groovy; you'll notice that the production environment does not delete the database file. That's exactly how you would need to set it up in your custom environment. By default both the development and test environment will delete the file.